# Aceder a servidor através do linux

Tags: java, linux, lado-do-servidor, cliente-servidor

Eu gostaria de com a minha aplicação em Java (netbeans) aceder à base de dados que está no servidor, mas isto ficou complicado, por ser através de uma maquina com Linux.

Alguém poderia me explicar como fazer isto?

A classe de conexão que eu uso é:

```
public Connection LigaBD() {
    try{
        System.out.println("Entrei !!!");
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:pesquisa.db");
        System.out.println("Passei a segunda fase !!!");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Nao consegui entrar na BD");
    return null;
}
```

Acedendo localmente eu consigo, o pior é mapear em Linux, sou novo em Linux.

Comment: Tu já tentou conectar via pgAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

Você se conecta a sua base de dados usando uma das seguintes formas:

- jdbc:sqlite:meu_banco.db
- jdbc:sqlite://dirA/dirB/meu_banco.db
- jdbc:sqlite:/DRIVE:/dirA/dirB/meu_banco.db
- jdbc:sqlite:///COMPUTADOR/shareA/dirB/meu_banco.db

No caso, a solução para seu problema seria usando a última forma:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:jdbc:sqlite:///NOME_SERVIDOR/caminho_do_arquivo/pesquisa.db");
```

Voê tem que criar um compartilhamento de arquivo no servidor, o que não é recomendável, já que pode abrir uma brecha na segurança do seu sistema.

O SQLite não é recomendado para aplicações cliente/servidor. Para isto, utilize outro SGBD. Use MySQL ou PostgreSQL (eu prefiro o PostgreSQL).

Comment: Duplicou `jdbc:sqlite:jdbc:sqlite:///...`